# SQLITE - Howto Ignore quotation-marks on import?

Tags: csv, sqlite

The background.
I've got "dirty" data that i need to import into SQLITE. I've got som 5-6 million lines everyday, so i'll need some kind of automation. The data comes in an .txt file, tab separated.

This is my code till now:

```
<<
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Import;
CREATE TABLE Import (field1 text,field2 text,field3 text,field4 text,field5 text,field6 text,field7 text,field8 text,field9 text,field10 text,field11 text);
.mode csv
.separator "\t"
.import MyFile.txt import

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM import;
>>
```

it works, however since the data contains (unclosed) " marks at the end of some of the lines, and my import therefore misses some 20% of the lines.
edit - Sample data added

```
name.2017   11301   KX_204  text/X1 text.url            2017-07-24 12:56:49.000     "t
name.2017   11301   KX_205  text/X2 text.url            2017-07-24 12:56:49.000     "th
name.2017   11301   KX_206  text/X3 text.url            2017-07-24 12:56:49.000     "the
name.2017   11301   KX_207  text/X4 text.url            2017-07-24 12:56:49.000     
name.2017   11301   KX_208  text/X5 text.url            2017-07-24 12:56:49.000     "da
```

If I do the import via SQLITE GUI (SQliteBrowser), it works fine when un-checking the "-box.

How do I accomplish the same from commandline?

Comment: Please edit your question to post a sample of the data you are trying to import. I dont understand why your import would "miss" data due to quotation marks.

Comment: I've made a dummyfile.txt that creates the error. When theres unclosed quotation-marks something goes wrong.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp9enh8of2lopgn/DummyFile.txt?dl=0
and btw  - I do not need that last field that contains the unclosed "-marks. It can be skipped if needed.

Comment: Having to register anywhere to get information on your question is not loved here. Please make a small enough sample input to show it here directly. You might find useful information in [mcve] and the [tour].

Comment: @Yunnosch - thanks, I didn't realise that. Dbox was (and has been for a long time) the goto file-share. Anyhow, I'll create an example and include in the question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could discard double quotes and anything that follows using `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/".*//' MyFile.txt > CleanedUp.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into sed. I did not know that tool.